# Localization using ultrasonic sensors

Tags: algorithm, robotics

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question.

I am working on a project in which I have to use ultrasonic sensors only to do "simultaneous localization and mapping" of robot. I have 8 such sensors. Assume that i have enough computation power and the limited sensing(8 ultrasonic sensor) capability.

What would be an appropriate algorithm to use in this case?

Comment: Dupe?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080533/slam-algorithm

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. Instead, that link should go into your answer to provide a starting point for implementing the algorithm you suggest ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [SLAM for Dummies](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/36832/16-412JSpring2004/NR/rdonlyres/Aeronautics-and-Astronautics/16-412JSpring2004/A3C5517F-C092-4554-AA43-232DC74609B3/0/1Aslam_blas_report.pdf) to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, the algorithm to use is SLAM.

There are many possible SLAM implementations. http://openslam.org